# Angular 2 *ngFor displaying value of the last item for all the items

Tags: angular2-directives

I have a product object, which consists of few fields along with an array of another components object. I am trying to render all the components. it is displaying the correct number of rows (based on the number of components), but all has values from the last object in the array. Here is the detail:
Product Obj: Product {productId, product desc, productComponents[]}
ProductComponent: {serviceCat, CGC}

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
   <form (ngSubmit)="addProduct()" #addProd="ngForm"> -->
      <div class="well" id="well1">
         <div *ngFor="let prodComp of selectedProduct.productComponents">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Service Category</span>
                            <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="serviceCat" 
                                    placeholder="Service Category" 
                                    [(ngModel)]="prodComp.serviceCategory"
                                    name="serviceCat" required>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Service Category -->

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">CGC</span>
                            <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="cgc" 
                                    placeholder="CGC" 
                                    [(ngModel)]="prodComp.cgc"
                                    name="cgc" required>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- CGC -->
            </div> <!-- row -->
         </div> <!-- for -->
       </div> <!-- well -->
    </form>
 </div> <!-- main div -->
```

I have 5 components in product object. it displays 5 rows, but all rows has the same value in serviceCategory and cgc input fields even though I see correct list of components in dev tool (F12) in IE.

Comment: Update: I think it is caused by <form> </form>. if I take out <form> tag then it is displaying the value correctly.  Does anyone know why <form> tag are causing it to display the last item?  Does <form> causes it not to render until the close of form tag?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was in fact due to form tag.